# rename the header of multifasta files

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have multi-fast files like this

```
>aaaaa.1_prot_CAA66754.1_10
MEKLLDAYLSSLRLNRRQVSEQTGLNYTTLQRASDKDALMISPRILWGIAMMVDKTPGQVLDELIELEMK
>bbbbb.1_prot_CAA66753.1_11
MMSKQDRINRRRRNIMKDAHRIAKLIVSNVGDYMVAMKLALKTVYAYKAMRKEVSSRGNAVEMHTLPLLD
GYARQQFEPEFVAGIPAWAIKKDFMSSSAQDILYFTIDTKVVKETEKAVEIEFATKNPKEHGYVDHHHTW
VAKSIMAA
```

I want to rename the header like this by `sed` or `awk`

```
>aaaaa.1_10
MEKLLDAYLSSLRLNRRQVSEQTGLNYTTLQRASDKDALMISPRILWGIAMMVDKTPGQVLDELIELEMK
>bbbbb.1_11
MMSKQDRINRRRRNIMKDAHRIAKLIVSNVGDYMVAMKLALKTVYAYKAMRKEVSSRGNAVEMHTLPLLD
GYARQQFEPEFVAGIPAWAIKKDFMSSSAQDILYFTIDTKVVKETEKAVEIEFATKNPKEHGYVDHHHTW
VAKSIMAA
```

but I just know `sed` a little, like

```
sed 's/.\(.\)$/\1/'
```

to remove the penultimate letter of each line,and retain the first occurrence of '-'

Comment: surely it is quite clear to those who know this type of format which part of the text you want to keep, but not to others.
In: "aaaaa.1_prot_CAA66754.1_10" must the entire string after the last point (.1_10) be saved? Or must the result be the join of the first number after the first period (aaaaa.1_) and the last number (10 in .1_10)? Since the root is the same (1_ and 1_10) it is not clear how to derive the field.

Comment: Wondering if `.` dots are field separators in your format? And you want to delete the second field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk` way to do it:

```
$ awk '/^>/{sub(/\.[^.]+/,"")}1' file
>aaaaa.1_10
MEKLLDAYLSSLRLNRRQVSEQTGLNYTTLQRASDKDALMISPRILWGIAMMVDKTPGQVLDELIELEMK
>bbbbb.1_11
MMSKQDRINRRRRNIMKDAHRIAKLIVSNVGDYMVAMKLALKTVYAYKAMRKEVSSRGNAVEMHTLPLLD
GYARQQFEPEFVAGIPAWAIKKDFMSSSAQDILYFTIDTKVVKETEKAVEIEFATKNPKEHGYVDHHHTW
VAKSIMAA
```

This will consider modify lines that start with a `>` (the header lines).

In these lines, it will replace the pattern "string starting with `.` and consisting of characters *not* including `.`" (which means the sequence of characters starting with the first `.`, up to and excluding the next `.`) with "nothing", thereby removing it.

The seemingly stray `1` outside of the rule block instructs `awk` to print the current line including all possible modifications made so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/_.*_/_/' file
        >aaaaa.1_10
        MEKLLDAYLSSLRLNRRQVSEQTGLNYTTLQRASDKDALMISPRILWGIAMMVDKTPGQVLDELIELEMK
        >bbbbb.1_11
        MMSKQDRINRRRRNIMKDAHRIAKLIVSNVGDYMVAMKLALKTVYAYKAMRKEVSSRGNAVEMHTLPLLD
        GYARQQFEPEFVAGIPAWAIKKDFMSSSAQDILYFTIDTKVVKETEKAVEIEFATKNPKEHGYVDHHHTW
        VAKSIMAA
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep aaaaa<del>.1_prot_CAA66754</del>.1_10:

```
sed '/^>/s/[.][^.]*//' sample
```

To keep aaaaa.1<del>_prot_CAA66754.1</del>_10:

```
sed '/^>/s/_[^.]*[.][^_]*//' sample
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove the part of the header from the first to the second dot, the following removes everything from the first dot up to but not including the second dot:

```bash
sed 's/\.[^.]*//' file
```

Or, removing everything from just after the first dot up to and including the second dot:

```bash
sed 's/[^.]*\.//2' file
```

I believe what you tried to do was the following, which captures the bit from the last dot to the end, and then replaces the whole string from the first dot with that captured string:

```bash
sed 's/\..*\(\..*\)/\1/' file
```

---

Using `awk` and treating each line as a set of dot-delimited fields, removing the second such field on each line that starts with a `>`:

```bash
awk -F . 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } /^>/ { $0 = $1 OFS $3 }; 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F "_" '/^>/{$0=$1"_"$NF}1' file
```

output

```
>aaaaa.1_10
MEKLLDAYLSSLRLNRRQVSEQTGLNYTTLQRASDKDALMISPRILWGIAMMVDKTPGQVLDELIELEMK
>bbbbb.1_11
MMSKQDRINRRRRNIMKDAHRIAKLIVSNVGDYMVAMKLALKTVYAYKAMRKEVSSRGNAVEMHTLPLLD
GYARQQFEPEFVAGIPAWAIKKDFMSSSAQDILYFTIDTKVVKETEKAVEIEFATKNPKEHGYVDHHHTW
VAKSIMAA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'if /^\>/ {.split(".").[0,2].join(".").put} else {.put};' 

#OR

raku -ne 'if .starts-with(">") {.split(".").[0,2].join(".").put} else {.put};'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '/^\>/ ?? .split(".").[0,2].join(".").put !! .put;'  

#OR

raku -ne '.starts-with(">") ?? .split(".").[0,2].join(".").put !! .put;'
```

These Raku answers considers each "word" as a series of characters separated by a `.` dot. Consequently, `split`ting on `.` dot allows you to take the `[0,2]` zero-indexed first and third elements, and return them (`join`ing back together with `.` dot again). The `if /^\>/` or `if .starts-with(">")` conditional ensures that only the header line of each fasta sequence is altered. The first two answers use '`if` (Condition) {True} `else` {False}' ; the second two answers use Raku's ternary operator, 'Condition `??` True `!!` False' .

OR...if you prefer an `awk`-ish answer (inspired by @AdminBee), or something `sed`-ish (inspired by @Kusalananda):

```
#Maybe awk-like?

raku -ne 'put .subst(/\.<-[.]>+/);' 

#Maybe sed-like?

raku -pe 's/\.<-[.]>+//;'
```

---

Sample Input:

```
>aaaaa.1_prot_CAA66754.1_10
MEKLLDAYLSSLRLNRRQVSEQTGLNYTTLQRASDKDALMISPRILWGIAMMVDKTPGQVLDELIELEMK
>bbbbb.1_prot_CAA66753.1_11
MMSKQDRINRRRRNIMKDAHRIAKLIVSNVGDYMVAMKLALKTVYAYKAMRKEVSSRGNAVEMHTLPLLD
GYARQQFEPEFVAGIPAWAIKKDFMSSSAQDILYFTIDTKVVKETEKAVEIEFATKNPKEHGYVDHHHTW
VAKSIMAA
```

Sample Output:

```
>aaaaa.1_10
MEKLLDAYLSSLRLNRRQVSEQTGLNYTTLQRASDKDALMISPRILWGIAMMVDKTPGQVLDELIELEMK
>bbbbb.1_11
MMSKQDRINRRRRNIMKDAHRIAKLIVSNVGDYMVAMKLALKTVYAYKAMRKEVSSRGNAVEMHTLPLLD
GYARQQFEPEFVAGIPAWAIKKDFMSSSAQDILYFTIDTKVVKETEKAVEIEFATKNPKEHGYVDHHHTW
VAKSIMAA
```

https://raku.org